# Why does the method of Lagrange multiplier fail here?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{extremize} & f(x,y) := 2 y \sqrt{y^2 - x^2}\\ \text{subject to} & \pi x^2 y = 450\end{array}$$

WolframAlpha says that the minimum is $0$, but the Lagrange multipliers method fails. The Lagrangian is

$$L = 2y\sqrt{y^2-x^2}+\lambda\left(\pi x^2y-450\right)$$

and

$$\begin{aligned} \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} &= -\frac{2xy}{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}}+2\pi\lambda xy\\ \frac{\partial L}{\partial y} &= 2\sqrt{y^2-x^2}+\frac{2y^2}{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}}+\pi\lambda x^2\\ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} &= \pi x^2y-450 \end{aligned}$$

This system only has [solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%5Cfrac%7B2xy%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7By%5E2-x%5E2%7D%7D%2B2%5Cpi%5Clambda%20*xy%3D0%2C2%5Csqrt%7By%5E2-x%5E2%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B2y%5E2%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7By%5E2-x%5E2%7D%7D%2B%5Cpi%5Clambda*%20x%5E2%3D0%2C%5Cpi%20x%5E2y-450%3D0), where the function is undefined.

Comment: You should show where it fails according to your work on that.

Comment: What happens with the Lagrange multipliers method?  Please share your work.

Comment: What's the domain of definition of $f$?

Comment: It is $y^2 \ge x^2$.

Comment: @Andrew Fount Notice Lagrange multipliers are a valid method for finding maxima in an open set. Is your domain open?

Answer (score 2):

Lagrange multipliers are useful for exploring open sets. In this case, your domain $y^2 \geq x^2$ is not open. Therefore the boundary $y^2 = x^2$ should be explored on its own. In those points you get: $$f(x,y) = 0$$ which is indeed the minimum. To find which point you want substitute in your extra equation $x$ by $y^2$

Answer (score 1):

Given the lagrangian

$$
L(x,y,\lambda) = f(x,y)+\lambda g(x,y)
$$

the stationary solutions are the solutions to

$$
\nabla f(x,y) +\lambda \nabla g(x,y) = 0
$$

so at the solutions we should have $\nabla f(x,y)\times \nabla g(x,y)=\vec 0$. In our case

$$
\cases{
\nabla f(x,y) = \left\{-\frac{2 x y}{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}},-\frac{2 \left(x^2-2 y^2\right)}{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}},0\right\}\\
\nabla g(x,y) = \left\{2 \pi  x y,\pi  x^2,0\right\}
}
$$

and $\nabla f(x,y)\times \nabla g(x,y)=\left\{0,0,\frac{2 \pi  x y \left(x^2-4 y^2\right)}{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}}\right\}$ now to have $-\epsilon\le \frac{2 \pi  x y \left(x^2-4 y^2\right)}{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}}\le\epsilon$. Making substitutions $x\to r\cos\theta, y\to r\sin\theta$ we have

$$
-\epsilon\le \frac{\pi  r^3 \sin (2 \theta ) (5 \cos (2 \theta )-3)}{2 \sqrt{-\cos (2 \theta )}}\le \epsilon
$$

so to have small $\epsilon$ suffices a small $r$ giving small $x$ and small $y$ but then $g(x,y) = \pi x^2y-450=0$ can't be verified. Resuming, no real solutions to the stationary points determination.